# XCode 5 Crashes when debugging multiple iOS Devices

Tags: xcode, xcode5

I've been debugging up to 4 devices at once recently for an iOS networking project with XCode 4. Having today updated to XCode 5 to be able to build to iOS7 devices, I've found that XCode will crash when ever I try to debug a second device simultaneously. The simulator seems to debug fine while one other device is debugging however.

The crash seems to be at the point where XCode tries to launch the app on the device. XCode immediately closes, and bring up the all too familiar 'Xcode quit unexpectedly' dialogue box. There doesn't appear to be anything all that helpful in the output other than the following.

```
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/DVTFoundation/DVTFoundation-3532/Framework/Classes/FoundationClassCategories/DVTNSKeyValueObserving.m:427
```

Anyone have any clues if there's something I can do about this or do I just have to wait for an update to fix the problem?

Comment: Heck, I'm amazed that even 4 could handle two at once!

Comment: What you should really do is file a bug with this information.

Comment: I disagree with the close vote(s): The problem doesn't concern code, its an issue with XCode. Please read the question before blindly voting.

Comment: @JamesWebster: Still, it's nothing that anyone here can help with. This is not an Apple bug forum.

Comment: @Goodsum: Please file a bug report with Apple.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the answers are unlikely to offer a workaround, and SO is not a bug reporting forum unless a fix is apparent.

Comment: I have observed that Xcode will crash randomly if it's been a long time since the Mac was last booted.  It appears that the system runs short on some sort of process handles or some such.