# Xcode 5 attach to process debugging. Debug server quits unexpectedly

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, xcode5

I have been using "Attach to process" feature from Xcode to attach debugger to running process .
This used to work fine with Xcode 4.

But with Xcode 5, debug server quits as soon app is put in background.
However debug server works fine if I do Xcode build and run. I see this issue only if I try to attach debugger app or process.

Any one else saw this problem?
Any suggestions is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Possibly related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18916219/xcode-5-crashes-when-debugging-multiple-ios-devices